# Android EditText lose focus istantly

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-nestedscrollview

I created an EditText into a CardView who is into a NestedScrollView. The EditText starts without focus, and the behaviour is ok. The problem is that when I touch the EditText to write, it get focus but lose it instantly and the InputSoftKeyboard does not appear.

I tried to use:

- in Manifest: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
- on the view: `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`

but them don't work

Comment: try adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`